# Optimizing JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have written the following JS, and it gets the job done, but I have been having a ton of trouble eliminating the repeating code. I keep breaking the functionality.

It's just field validation using a `regex`, and adding an error message below the appropriate field if the input doesn't match the `regex`. It's works, but but I really want to begin writing more succinct code.

If someone can help me do this, I can compare mine and yours and start understanding how to approach this type of task.

Thanks.

```
<form></form>
```

Here's my JSFiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/robinburrage/cnL2d4w8/2/

Comment: please post your code here.

Comment: @j08691 This question would be severely off-topic at Code Review. Please read our [on-topic help centre](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and be a bit more careful when recommending CR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse the same function for all the 2 validations. The only difference between the 3 functions is that you are trying to append to a different `id`.

Use `this` instead of referring to the element specifically, since the input is anyways bound to the element you are looking for.

```
phone.addEventListener('keyup', validatePhone);
phone2.addEventListener('keyup', validatePhone);
phone3.addEventListener('keyup', validatePhone);

function validatePhone(evt) {    
    var pattern = /^(\(\d{1,2}\)\s)?\(?\d{4}\-\)?[\s.-]?\d{4}$/; //set the regular expression
    var str = this.value; //get the user's input
    var phoneVal = document.getElementById("phoneVal");
    if (phoneVal) { //if the error message div is already on the page
        phoneVal.parentNode.removeChild(phoneVal); //remove it, to prevent a series of error message divs from accumulating
    }
    if (str === "") {//if there is no user input
        phoneVal.parentNode.removeChild(phoneVal);//remove the error message
    }
    if (pattern.test(str) === false) { //if the string doesn't match the expression            
        var elem = document.createElement("div"); //create a DIV
        elem.setAttribute("id", "phoneVal"); //give it an 1)id, 2)class and 3)message
        elem.setAttribute("class", "form-error-msg");   
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("/en") > -1) {
            elem.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid telephone number.'; 
        }else{
            elem.innerHTML = 'Por favor introduce un número de teléfono válido.'; 
        }            
        this.parentNode.appendChild(elem); //add the div with the current error message
    }   
} //end function
```

Comment: Oh no. I just noticed that even though I am testing against a regular expression that seems to work beautifully in debuggex.com, In my code (at the JSFiddle link above) the error message goes away even if the user enters letters. I know the hiding and showing of the error message is entirely separate from the actual validation piece, so one may have nothing to do with the other, but can anyone shed some light, please?